# Parsing rss feed. Some fields undefined

Tags: parsing, rss, undefined

I am attempting to parse this rss feed - http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/index.rss

I am using the following code to parse it:

```
 $.ajax({
        url      : document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' +
        encodeURIComponent('http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/index.rss'),
        dataType : 'json',
        success  : function (data) {
          if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
            $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
              console.log("------------------------");
              console.log("title      : " + e.title);
              console.log("link      : " + e.link);
              console.log("pubDate     : " + e.pubDate);
              console.log("description     : " + e.description);
              console.log("pubDate     : " + e.pubDate);
              console.log("guid: " + e.guid);
            });
          }
        }
      });
```

In the console.log only the title and the link appear. The description, pubDate and guid are all undefined.

Could someone be so kind as to explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whole "schema" of the response given by Google using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/julien51/8800583).

You'll see that each entry has the following items:

- title
- link
- author
- publishedDate
- contentSnippet
- content
- categories

So, unfortuately for you the `guid` is missing. You'll have to use `content` (or `contentSnippet`) instead of description and `publishedDate` instead of `pubDate`. If you really need the `guid`check out the [alternative offred by Superfeedr](http://blog.superfeedr.com/jquery-superfeedr/) (I created Superfeedr!).